# Java неверно работает isUpperCase с русскими символами

Tags: java, символы

```
        if (m_capsAllow == false){
        int numOfUpper = 0; int numOfLower = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
            if (Character.isUpperCase(message.charAt(i))){
                numOfUpper++;
            }
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(message.charAt(i))){
                numOfLower++;
            }
        }
        if (numOfUpper > numOfLower){
            sendTwitchMessage(channel, "caps");
        }
    }
}
```

Работает верно с латинскими символами, но с русскими символами и строчные, и заглавные строки считает за капс. Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 3):

Какая версия java? Может с локалью проблемы? На вход корректное сообщение приходит? Попробуй вывести message перед проверкой.

Проверь так:

```
char[] lower = {'й','ц','у','к','е','н','г','ш','щ','з','х','ъ','ф','ы','в','а','п','р','о','л','д','ж','э','ё','я','ч','с','м','и','т','ь','б','ю'};
char[] upper = {'Й','Ц','У','К','Е','Н','Г','Ш','Щ','З','Х','Ъ','Ф','Ы','В','А','П','Р','О','Л','Д','Ж','Э','Ё','Я','Ч','С','М','И','Т','Ь','Б','Ю'};

System.out.println("LOWERCASE: ");
for (char c : lower) {
    System.out.print(Character.isLowerCase(c) + ", ");
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("UPPERCASE: ");
for (char c : upper) {
    System.out.print(Character.isUpperCase(c) + ", ");
}
```

У меня вывод корректный: везде true